# Implementing array bound canaries in C

Tags: c, gcc, memory, embedded

I would like to scatter some canaries in strategic positions in the data layout of a C program (with GCC, for embedded), to serve for checking whether some pointer ran into the wild.

Something like the following:

```
const volatile uint32_t canary_0 = CANARY_DEF;
static uint32_t some_global_array_0[SOME_SIZE_0] = {0};
const volatile uint32_t canary_1 = CANARY_DEF;
static uint32_t some_global_array_1[SOME_SIZE_1] = {0};
...
```

Of course I know that sample above is **not functional**, just for the idea. I would like to use something alike in safety-critical embedded software as an additional point for fallback, when all else (such as the usual array index bounds assertions etc.) fail to operate correctly.

I read [this post on the GCC mailing list](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2009-03/msg00046.html) (I am scared to think that "craft" is to be interpreted as in "aircraft"...), suggesting to use structures. The problem is that in larger scale it feels like it would severely mess up program structure, losing more for this (developer pulling out hair & making bugs because of it) than winning by implementing such a failsafe mechanism.

For now my best bet would be using linker scripts (like necessary anyway to implement stack canaries) to split the RAM up in various segments, scattering canaries inbetween. This is however feels somewhat fragile, needing maintenance. (Or maybe not so? For now I know little of LD's linker scripts, only sufficient for the basics like adding a code flash CRC, stack canaries, and the like to the default script used for the micro. Right now I even lack the knowledge of how to make a flexible layout which would adapt to the amount of data allocated in sections)

For my purposes considering threads and messing up some operating system's structures are not of concern (for the point of actually being able to fall back when the situation arise), as here we design single threaded software architectures with no third-party components. If the main thread can't go around eventually reaching the fallback code, the watchdog kills it. It is OK to involve those in an answer, but please don't just post an answer stating something like this won't work because of an RTOS goofing up.

Comment: Maybe compiling (using a recent GCC) with `-fsanitize=` options should help

Comment: Nice tip, I will suggest adding this to our testing. However here I would also like something which is capable to catch bad behavior in production code running on the field (that is, it can actually do something if it happens, say, drop some bytes for logging in low power regs, then get stuck in an infinite loop so the watchdog can bite it's butt).

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, the only reliable way to ensure that two data pieces are (nearly, up to alignment and padding) contiguous is to put them in a single aggregate (e.g. array or `struct`). Otherwise the compiler is permitted to optimize.

You might consider

```
volatile struct {
  uint32_t my1_canary_0 = CANARY_DEF;
  uint32_t my1_array_0[SOME_SIZE_0] = {0};
} my1;
#define canary0 my1.my1_canary_0
#define array0 my1.my1_array_0
```

<sup>So we are using structures, but the two macros above are "hiding" them!</sup>

However, I am not sure that declaring this entire `struct` to be `volatile` is a good idea 
(maybe it might be enough to have only the canary be volatile). It might slow down significantly your code.

The main point is where and how do you check for the canary? You could do that manually (but it is tedious), adding a lot of

```
assert (canary0 == CANARY_DEF);
```

at many places (or your own `assert`-like checking). You could also consider customizing GCC with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) for such purposes
(e.g. adding an optimization pass which would add the equvalent of above code inside every block accessing `array0`). Of course that requires a few weeks of work.

As I commented, the `-fsanitize=` options of recent GCC should also be helpful.

Comment: Checking canaries. Since this is a fallback (not something primary), the checks are supposed to be aggregated in one component (supervisor). Having checks for the canary within the source in question somewhat defeats their purpose (assuming the appropriate pointer checks are in place): the fallback is supposed to activate if for any programming (and testing) oversight, something still breaks. Then code containing the check may not run at all, however within the supervisor the watchdog can be tied with the result of the aggregated canary tests.

Comment: Adding asserts are good, however we use a specific function for this which works (and logs) proper in production code, so will fail even if the testing process failed to spot something. However it is nicer (when feasible) to create sanity checks which operate independent of the component in question since the component's code will fill up with "safety turd" anyway bringing the actual algorithm near beyond recognition. This canary fallback would be a good (and fast) candidate for such an independent safeguard if it was possible to add the canaries somehow.